# Bootstrap carousel moving to top when clicking next and before buttons?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

Now I have this carousel I made with Bootstrap code:

```
  <div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide d-none d-sm-none d-md-block" data-ride="carousel">
             <div class="carousel-inner">
                 <div class="carousel-item active">
                     <div class="row logo justify-content-center">
                         <div class="col">
                            <img class="image-logo" src="img/..." alt=""/>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col">
                            <img class="image-logo" src="img/..." alt=""/>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="carousel-item">
                   <div class="row logo justify-content-center">
                       <div class="col">
                          <img class="image-logo" src="img/..." alt=""/>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col">
                          <img class="image-logo" src="img/..." alt=""/>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                 <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                 <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
             </a>
             <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="next">
                 <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                 <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
             </a>
         </div>
```

When I press next and prev butttons, the page moves itself to the top of the browser. How can I disable this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, @Jaime, it means that your carousel is not working properly. Have you included/linked the necessary files from bootstrap (e.g. javascript,css)? Is the console in dev tools showing any error?

Comment: perhaps you can also specify what Boostrap version you're using :)

Comment: Please provide more details, try to add a snippet which reproduces the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on my site.

Fix:
`href="#carouselExample"` change to `href="/#carouselExample"`

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem. For me, the problem was that I had some jQuery code that was set to automatically scroll to links that had an anchor (#). I solved it by adding a no-scroll class to the carousel prev and next links and then excluding links with a class of no-scroll from the jQ code:

```
.not('.no-scroll')
```

Answer (score -1):

try to remove

```
href="#carouselExample"
```

Comment: the id of the first div is "carouselExample" and in the two button you bust in href "#carouselExample" so the page will moves automticly to the div

Comment: Can you check this ex: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel&stacked=h

Comment: try to add the ol and the li to know the datatarget